# How to verify file exit of not from bat file

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

1.Please enter file path in cmd file
2.Then verify this file exits of not
3.In not then enter again message

Already try if exist code but it not working

```
:IMP_FILE
echo import from csv !
set /p CSV_FILE=Pres enter csv file path .
echo CSV_FILEfile
IF EXIST CSV_FILE
echo CSV_FILE file exist !
IF NOT EXIST CSV_FILE goto file_not_exit
goto :done

:file_not_exit
echo file not found please enter again
goto IMP_FILE
```

If i enter some thing then press enter command prompt closed

Answer (score 1):

```
:IMP_FILE
echo import from csv !
set /p CSV_FILE=Pres enter csv file path .
echo %CSV_FILE%file
IF EXIST %CSV_FILE% goto file_find
IF NOT EXIST %CSV_FILE% goto file_not_exit
goto :done

:file_not_exit
echo file not found please enter again
goto IMP_FILE

:file_find
echo file found
goto :done
```

Comment: Downvoting because you haven't provided any explanation for your answer, please keep in mind that this is NOT a codewriting service.

Answer (score 0):

1.) The first issue here is that your code is missing a function that is called. You should add a done function to your code in order for it to make sense.

2.) There is an error in your program logic contained within this section:

```
IF EXIST CSV_FILE
echo CSV_FILE file exist !
IF NOT EXIST CSV_FILE goto file_not_exit
goto :done
```

It appears as though you don't do anything except for echo a message and then go to your alleged 'done' function. This is the culprit in causing your code to close the window instantly.
After correcting those errors, your code should look something like this:

```
:IMP_FILE
echo import from csv !
set /p CSV_FILE=Pres enter csv file path .
echo %CSV_FILE%file
IF EXIST %CSV_FILE% goto file_find
IF NOT EXIST %CSV_FILE% goto file_not_exit
goto :done

:file_not_exit
echo file not found please enter again
goto IMP_FILE

:file_find
echo file found
goto :done

:done
echo Execution complete!
pause
exit
```

Note: I have included a 'pause' statement in here for the sake of debugging. This will allow your code to execute properly (if compiled) and the cmd window should remain open regardless whether the file was found or not.